# itoa creates an infinite loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop, itoa

This is very strange. `itoa();` seems to create an infinite loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        char buffer[1];
        itoa(i, buffer, 10);
        std::cout << buffer;
}
```

Why on earth does it do that? I've tried using different variables than `i`, numerical values without variables (i.e. `itoa(1, buffer, 10);`), it still keeps ending up in an infinite loop.
I've tried to google without much success, I found an old mail about it [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/avr-gcc-list/2001-04/msg00038.html).
I am using Windows XP 32 bit and Code::Blocks (with GCC) as a compiler.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `boost::lexical_cast` instead.

Comment: Or stringstreams directly (which lexical_cast uses).

Comment: `itoa` isn't a standard function and really you should avoid it. `snprintf()` is a safe way to do what you're doing, as well as a number of others.

Comment: @Xeo : `lexical_cast` was changed some time ago to be implemented in terms of `sprintf`/`snprintf` for primitive types due to the poor performance of standard IO streams.

Comment: @BrianRoach, I'll check out `snprintf()`. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @ildjarn: Oh, thanks for the info. It really makes me wonder if the extensibility and type safety of IO streams can be matched with the speed of the C functions...

Comment: @Xeo : Of course -- even **faster** than the C functions, in fact! (though at the expense of compile times) [Boost.Spirit.Karma](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/tutorials/quick_start.html) :-) (See specifically [these benchmarks](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/performance_measurements/numeric_performance.html).)

Comment: Since when does GCC support itoa?

Comment: @DonReba So it's not supported? I had no idea, how come it compiles then? Obviously there's some sort of reference to it since it actually loops, hmmm oh well. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @ildjarn: I really need to look into Boost.Spirit sometime... Though, to be fair, their code for iostreams is not really fair thanks to the constant reset of the stream, though I don't have any better way currently in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itoa` null-terminates the string it produces, but you haven't made `buffer` large enough to hold the terminating NUL character. Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    char buffer[2];
    itoa(i, buffer, 10);
    std::cout << buffer;
}
```

Comment: @ildjarn Already tried that, it didn't work. Sorry, I guess I should've mentioned it (didn't do it because I knew it was going to be a terminating null there, but to try different stuff). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Xeo, a three byte char ends up in an infinite loop aswell.

Comment: @Griffin : This works as a standalone example, so if it doesn't work for you then it's related to code you've not shown us, or you have a faulty build environment.

Comment: @ildjarn Very strange, as I only have an unused function (which I just commented out). Other than that, that's the only code I have except for library inclusions and the `main()` function and `return 0;`.

Comment: I suppose my build environment is a different topic, so I'll just go ahead and give you an accepted answer. Thank you very much for your help, @ildjarn.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth are you using a general number conversion routine for single digits?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << char('0' + i);
```

(You need the cast back to `char` so that the compiler uses the correct overload of `<<`. The C++ standard guarantees that the character constants `'0'` through `'9'` have consecutive numeric values.)

Comment: My original post was only a quick example, I'm going to use `itoa()` for much larger numbers (characters) in my real program. 52 possible characters, to be precise. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Oh, well, in that case, yeah, you want `snprintf`.  Or just give up on iostreams and use good old `[f]printf`.  Iostreams are not enough better than stdio.h to be worth using, in my opinion.

Comment: @Zack : Type safety is not something to be shrugged off.

Comment: Type safety is nice, but it's not enough of a benefit to compensate for the verbosity and the awkward and the missing features.

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is too small -- itoa will write a null-terminated string, so your buffer will need at a minimum 2 bytes to hold values from 0-9.

Comment: Tried with two and three bytes, doesn't help. Thanks for your answer.